# tail -f | sed to file doesn't work

Tags: shell, sed, pipe, filtering, tail

I am having an issue with filtering a log file that is being written and writing the output to another file (if possible using `tee`, so I can see it working as it goes).

I can get it to output on stdout, but not write to a file, either using `tee` or `>>`.
I can also get it to write to the file, but only if I drop the `-f` options from tail, which I need.

So, here is an overview of the commands:

1. `tail -f` without writing to file: `tail -f test.log | sed 's/a/b/'` **works**
2. `tail` writing to file: `tail test.log | sed 's/a/b/' | tee -a a.txt` **works**
3. `tail -f` writing to file: `tail -f test.log | sed 's/a/b/' | tee -a a.txt` **doesn't output on stdout nor writes to file**.

I would like 3. to work.

Comment: How much data are you letting run through before you look at the output file? If it's not enough to flush the buffers... well, there's your problem. Once there's been enough input, or the `tail` process exits, `sed` will finish writing.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009).

Comment: See also [this duplicative question on Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/59497/writing-tail-f-output-to-another-file).

Comment: ...so, (2) works because your `tail test.log` hits EOF, so `sed` flushes its output when there's no more input. And (1) works because `sed` operates in line-buffered mode by default if its output is to the TTY.

Comment: That said, if you try to "fix" the problem by forcing line-buffered or unbuffered mode, you're creating a performance penalty in return for that latency improvement (smaller writes == more context-switch operations from userspace to the kernel). Which may make sense for your workload -- just note that it the latency improvement is not free-of-charge.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @CharlesDuffy. I was too focused on `sed`, probably why the `grep`-related solution eluded me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `sed` buffering. Use `sed -u`. `man sed`:

```
-u, --unbuffered

          load  minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the
          output buffers more often
```

And here's a test for it (creates files `foo`and `bar`):

```
$ for i in {1..3} ; do echo a $i ; sleep 1; done >> foo &
[1] 12218
$ tail -f foo | sed -u 's/a/b/' | tee -a bar
b 1
b 2
b 3
```

Be quick or increase the `{1..3}` to suit your skillz.